# How to extract data from this JSON ? (PHP)

Tags: php, json, testing

```
[{"id":"1",name":"Test 1","players":"999"},{"id":"2","name":"Test 2","players":"100"}]
```

How do I print pull data?

Comment: Perhaps there is no pull data to print?

Answer (score 1):

Your json is invalid (missing a quote). I fixed it below.

```
$j='[{"id":"1","name":"Test 1","players":"999"},{"id":"2","name":"Test 2","players":"100"}]';
$a=json_decode($j,true);
print_r($a);
```

Use json_decode. The "true" value makes it return an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

Your data that you're trying to use has an error. In the first object, "name" has no opening quotation. *Use PHP's [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) functionality after you correct that error.*

**Note:** You should be able to pass the json data as a variable into the function with the boolean value set to true and for now just run a print_r to view your data as it's decoded.